# Windows 10: Disable the permanently delete file option

Tags: windows, windows-10

Unfortunately I was addicted to permanently deleting files using the "Shift" key. 
And obviously I regret it from time to time.

Is there a way to disable this option - meaning to be able to ONLY safe delete the file to the Recycle Bin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may disable the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> keyboard combination
and make it equivalent to <kbd>Delete</kbd>, by using the free [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Create an AutoHotKey script in a file named `yourname.ahk` with this one line :

```
+Delete::Send {Delete}
```

This will block the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key combination
and only pass the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to Windows.

To test the file, double-click it to launch. Notice that it will have
a green "H" icon in the traybar, which you may right-click to exit while testing.

Once it is proven as working, place it in the
[Windows Startup folder](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/startup-folder-in-windows-8).

For more information about AutoHotKey see the
[AutoHotkey Beginner Tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).

Comment: it is not very good solution if one has to install 3rd party programs, don't you think OP couldn't do this on his own if he wanted... no offense, just saying

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the newer version of this program, but the script you mention above doesn't work with it. Tried to revert to v.1, but I keep getting redirected to v.2. Can you, (a) provide a new syntax that works with v.2, or (b) indicate how to override the use of v.2? Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).